# Create a folder shortcut/redirection in Vista

Tags: windows-vista, windows-explorer, folder-redirection

Given a plain old directory of files in Windows Vista, say *"C:\OldFolder\"*, is it possible to move the contents of that directory to a new location, perhaps *"F:\NewFolder\"* and keep a shortcut-like 'virtual' folder at *C:\OldFolder* that will always redirect access to the updated location.

Shortcuts work for users accessing through the GUI to some extent, but all application links to the old location won't work anymore even with a shortcut.  For example, If MS Word tried to access C:\OldFolder\document.doc I would want Windows to simply rewrite it's request to F:\NewFolder\document.doc...

I guess I'm basically looking for Apache's Mod_Rewrite for Windows Vista...  any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a symbolic link with the [mklink](http://technet.microsoft.com/es-es/library/cc753194(WS.10).aspx) tool.

e.g.

```
mklink /d \OldFolder F:\NewFolder
```

Comment: You're most welcome!