# How to wildcard redirect a folder (not alias) in Windows?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, redirection, onedrive, folder-redirection

We just moved a lot of company data in a folder to OneDrive for Business.

We used to have everything located in "**D:\BusinessFiles**", now they're all located in "**D:\OneDrive - Contoso**". Since OneDrive for business doesn't allow the renaming of the root directory, we have no option, but to have a different root directory.

However, there are many shortcuts that still point to "D:\BusinessFiles", I need to **redirect** them all to "D:\OneDrive - Contoso", like it is done in HTTP (301 and 302).

I tried using '**mklink**' for '**Junction**' and '**Symbolic link**', both act as if the files still exist in the folder (like an alias).

So, is there anyway **redirect** folders in Windows?

Thanks,

Comment: [Create a folder shortcut/redirection in Vista](https://superuser.com/questions/229735/create-a-folder-shortcut-redirection-in-vista?rq=1) mentions Vista but applicable to all supported versions of Windows.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create a folder shortcut/redirection in Vista](https://superuser.com/questions/229735/create-a-folder-shortcut-redirection-in-vista)

Comment: Related: [Windows 7 Virtual Folders?](https://superuser.com/questions/373315/windows-7-virtual-folders/373317#373317)

Comment: @Ramhound sorry, that is not what I meant. That creates an alias, as mentioned in my question, not a redirect

Comment: @Ramhound nop, that creates an alias, not a redirection. So, it's not a duplicate

Comment: You are the one who used the term “redirect”.

Comment: @Ramhound yes, I meant an actual redirect, not an alias. Redirect similar to 301 in HTTP, but, in Windows explorer rather